# Magento - add extra js validation rules globally

Tags: javascript, validation, magento

I want to add some extra validation rules to my customer fields that are not in prototype/validation.js .

As I read on the net, I can add the rule by `Validation.add()` in my .phtml file.

Is there any way to make those extra rules known in the whole .phtml files, like required-entry ?

****Of cource** I know that updating validation.js would not be a wise choice , due to the updates of magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create js file with below code and add it globally.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theForm = new VarienForm('theForm', true);
Validation.add('validate-rule','validatio message!',function(the_field_value){
    if(the_field_value == 'baz')
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a site specific JS file for your website and write the Validation.add code in that js, just make sure that the site specific js is being called after validation.js. Add the site specific js to page.xml so it is loaded on all pages,  this way you addition to the code becomes global throughout the site.

Comment: tnx for the answer, also I found out that I can add the js file to the head.phtml of each theme, if I want to use one js file in just one theme.